# Create a pdf bookmark for every istance of a newcommand

Tags: pdf, bookmarks

I'm composing a document where there's a long list of UNIX shell commands and their main options explained. All the UNIX commands are written with a `\newcommand` LaTeX command, so I can easily change their formatting in one shot. As there are a lot of UNIX command entries, I want to make for each one a PDF bookmark to easily navigate through them and, for this purpouse, I've used the *bookmark* package. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\newcommand{\cmd}[1]{\pdfbookmark[2]{#1}{unixcommand}\textcolor{blue}{\texttt{{\large #1}}}}
\begin{document}
\cmd{ls} → list the files
\begin{itemize}
  \item \texttt{-l} = foo bar
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

It works pretty well: I see all the commands bookmarks in the internal index of the PDF reader, but each one brings to the first `\cmd{}` entry of the document, and not to the correct one. Is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: Does `\pdfbookmark[2]{#1}{#1}` instead of `\pdfbookmark[2]{#1}{unixcommand}` help? The second mandatory argument of `\pdfbookmark` is an internal name for the link destination. If you use the same identifier (`unixcommand`) for all calls, you always link to the same guy. With `#1` you use the command name as identifier for the link, that works as long as you use `\cmd` at most once for each command.

Comment: For future reference please note that the code as shown is almost, but not quite a minimal example in the sense of https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864. It does not load `xcolor` and so `\textcolor{blue}` is undefined and throws an error. And it does not reproduce the issue because it only calls `\cmd` once.

Comment: Thanks @moewe for the help, the issue is resolved. Only a little question: why don't you post the solution in the "answer" space (so the question can be marked as resolved)? Sorry for the question, I'm a newbie in TeX StackExchange.

Comment: I'll write up an answer in a few minutes. Because the code wasn't complete, I couldn't really test my suggestion the way I normally test them and I wasn't too sure if this is exactly what you wanted. In those cases I leave a comment and if the asker is happy with it I convert it to an answer. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3238/35864 on meta and the many linked discussions.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`hyperref` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf) (p. 21) explains `\pdfbookmark` thus (emphasis mine)

> `\pdfbookmark[<level>]{<text>}{<name>}` creates a bookmark with the specified test [`<text>`] and at the given level [`<level>`] (default is 0). As name for the internal anchor `<name>` is used (in conjunction with level). *Therefore the name must be unique (similar to `\label`).*

As defined in the question, `\cmd` will issue `\pdfbookmark[2]{#1}{unixcommand}`, which means that the `<name>` is not unique (it is always `unixcommand`).
And indeed, if you look at the `.log` file of a document that uses `\cmd` twice, you find

```
pdfTeX warning (ext4):
destination with the same identifier (name{unixcommand.2})
has been already used, duplicate ignored

\AtBegShi@Output ...ipout \box \AtBeginShipoutBox 
                                                  \fi \fi 
l.15 \end{document}
                   ] (asddaasdasdasd.aux) )
```

(unfortunately, this warning is formatted differently from other LaTeX warnings and is harder to spot for us humans and might not be picked up by your editor either).

We need to make sure that each `\cmd` creates a unique label to link back to.

```
\newcommand*{\cmd}[1]{%
  \pdfbookmark[2]{#1}{unixcommand:#1}%
  \textcolor{blue}{\texttt{{\large #1}}}}
```

would work. Note that this still requires that you only call `\cmd` only once for every command you want to mention.